# Q - Given positive integers- m,n.. Find and print the values of 3^min(m,n) and 2^max(m,n)

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements, max

Using C++  have written foloowing :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int m,n;
    int threemin, twomax;
    threemin = 1; twomax = 1;
    cout<<"Enter m"<<"Enter n";
    cin>>m>>n;
    int i,j;
    for ((i = 1, j = 1) ; ( (i <= m), (j <= n) ) ; (i++,j++))
    {
        if (m>n){ i <= n ; threemin = threemin*3;}  //  for changing max value of i if m > n because we want to print 3^min(m,n)
        else {  threemin = threemin*3 ;} ; // 
        if (m>n){ j <= m ; twomax = twomax*2;} // same for changing j
        else {  twomax = twomax*2 ; } 
        
        
    }
    cout<<"Threemax is"<<threemin<<"Twomax is"<<twomax;
    return 0;
    
}
```

Issue -

1. For example m = 4 and n = 3 but here max(4,3) = 4 and min(4,3) = So, I have tried to such code which will give 3^min(m,n) and 2 ^max(4,3).
   But Output comes out to be threemin = 3^3 = 81 and twomax = 2^3 = 8. Both are taking n as their exponent.

I am beginner .Kindly help me rectifying .

Comment: What do you expect a statement like the following does: `j <= m ;` `j <= n;`? Can you elaborate about the reason you've written that please?

Comment: Also please reformat so it's readable.  Provide actual output for your two issues, and what you expect.  You don't need () the 3 parts of the for loop.  Usually no space after if and for.  The comma operator in the condition is odd.

Comment: What do you think `( (i <= m), (j <= n) )` will do? It's also not really clear what the task is. Find the minimum and maximum of a sequence of numbers and do some funny calculations with it?

Comment: To limit maximum values of j - j <= m ; and j <= n;
Same for i - ( i <= m )

Comment: It would be much simpler to have two loops.

Comment: This is not what `( (i <= m), (j <= n) )` does. [Comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) What you want to achieve would be expressed as `i <= m && j <= n` or `i <= m || j <= n`. (Your intention is not clear to me.) [Logical operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical)

Comment: I have done using double  but tutor said we can do this by single loop too.

Comment: @Scheff I got it . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can instead do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int m, n, lesser, greater, threemin=1, twomax=1, i=1;

    cout << "Enter m " << "Enter n";
    cin >> m >> n;

    lesser = min(m, n);     // find smallest
    greater = max(m, n);    // find largest

    while(i <= lesser) {    // ride on smallest untill done
        threemin *= 3;
        twomax *= 2;
        i++;
    }

    while(i <= greater) {    // continue for largest
        twomax *= 2;
        i++;
    }

    cout << "Threemin is: " << threemin << ", Twomax is: " << twomax;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , I just started learning programming at that time.Now I have understood what was my mistake